# Setting href to Hyperlink text

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am getting below text from database with `href` as null.

> You also have to click on this  link .

This text I am assigning to the label when page loads.
My requirement is when I click the "link"  I need to redirect to certain page. Where should I assign the `href` value and how?

Comment: cant you just do <a href="link">link</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var s = document.getElementByTagName("a");
s.href = ""; // here give the href value
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **jQuery** you can set the href using the following code:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the aspx page you can write the following line to create a placeholder

```
<div><%= linkValue %></div>
```

And in the code behind create a global variable

```
    string linkValue = "You also have to click on is <a href='' target='_blank'> link </a>"; 
    /* Set the page URL where you want to redirect the page. in your case get the value from database. */";
```

I think this is what you want to do. It was not completely clear from the question.

**Updates:**
In case you have multiple links in the page you need to create the link along with label.
See the code below

```
HyperLink link1 = new HyperLink();
link1.Text = "LINK HERE";
link1.NavigateUrl = "http://somedomain.com";
```

And add to the container like this

```
container.Controls.Add(link1);
```

Comment: I am getting the link details from database                        You also have to click on is                                          <a href="" target="_blank"> link </a>.                            In my code behind I am assigning the above message to a label.how to add href to link ?

Comment: can you please add the code for creating the label and setting its value?

Comment: Instead of assigning the value to a label, you can put the place holder inside the aspx page itself. I have updated code. If there are multiple links in your page, you need to create the link dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="http://www.google.com";
```

Simple enough :)

In case, you also want to Change URL and text of the hyperlink...

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myHref(){
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="Visit Google"
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="http://www.google.com"
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.java2s.com">Visit Java2s</a>
    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="myHref()" value="Change URL and text">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Source: [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/ChangeURLandtextofahyperlink.htm)