# How to assign href to anchor tag in codebehind c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The text I inserted in database is

```
 You also have to click on is <a href="" target="_blank"> link </a>
```

This text I am assigning to the label when page loads. My requirement is when I click the "link" I need to redirect to certain page. How can I  set the href to the above code in code behind .

Comment: Are you able to change the format of text you insert into the database or is that set in stone? This sort of problem is much easier if you have a placeholder in the href that you can replace rather than trying to detect where the href is...

Comment: Check the answer I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049867/setting-href-to-hyperlink-text/14052197#14052197)

Answer (score 9):

Try to use HyperLink.

```
 <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
                  ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
                  NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"
                  Text="Microsoft Official Site"
                  Target="_new"
                  runat="server"/>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should add runat="server" to your anchor and then give an ID to it. So you can edit href property in codebehind.

in html side:

in code behind:  xxxxx.HRef = "bla bla"

Look at this:
[How do you set href attribute of anchor tag that is within a repeater in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976659/how-do-you-set-href-attribute-of-anchor-tag-that-is-within-a-repeater-in-code-be)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can slightly change the format of what you put in the database then I'd do something along these lines:

```
string labelFromDatabase="You also have to click on is <a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\"> link </a>";
string url = "mypage.aspx";
myLabel.Text = String.Format(labelFromDatabase, url);
```

Adding in the `{0}` placeholder into the database held string means you can easily just use `String.Format` to put in whatever url you want.

Main things to be aware of are that putting `{` or `}` in the DB string will need special care (since they are special characters when you pass it into `String.Format`. Also you will of course need to make sure that url is appropriately escaped if necessary (but that is the case with all solutions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But it is not working as we expected.after the formatting the string I am getting the output as                         You also have to click on is <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"> link </a> ....So when i click the link it is checking for localhost/google.com.Any suggestions??

Comment: You just have to make sure that what you put in is correct in the href. In this case your href is a relative link to `www.google.com` so will look for something of that name in the current location. If you want it to go to that website you need `http://www.google.com/`

Comment: @lakki: Don't forget that you can vote up any answer that you found helpful (using the up arrow above the score just to the left of the answer) and if you feel an answer does successfully address all your problems you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the little tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string Myurl="index.aspx";
label1.Text = "You also have to click on is <a href=" + Myurl+ " target="_blank"> link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to store your string in database with some formate like this...

```
 "You also have to click on is <a href='{0}' target='_blank'> link </a>"
```

and when you assign that text to your lable at that time use string.formate method to add URL to href like this...

```
//get your database string
string _samplestring ="You also have to click on is <a href='{0}' target='_blank'> link </a>";
string _url ="http://stackoverflow.com/";
lbl.Text = string.Format(_samplestring, _url);
```

if you also need to assign something to target at run time then store your string like this..

```
"You also have to click on is <a href='{0}' target='{1}'> link </a>"
```

and use it like this...

```
//get your database string
string _samplestring ="You also have to click on is <a href='{0}' target='{1}'> link </a>";
string _url ="http://stackoverflow.com/";
string _target = "_blank";
lbl.Text = string.Format(_samplestring, _url,_target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for assigning string to href in anchor tag which is created in code behind

> string strstring = "../master/YourPage.aspx?TransID="+ dr["TransId"];

Assign this string to url

```
marqueeText += "<a href='"+strstring+"'" + <span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'>"
+ Convert.ToString(dr["SocietyName"]) + "</span></a>";
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

simplest workaround is to add 'runat' attribute with 'server' value, and set Target and Href properties.

//in design

```
<a id="aBack" runat="server">
  <img src="backarrow.png" style="cursor: pointer;" width="32px" height="32px" />
</a>
```

//in Code behind C#

aBack.Target = "_parent";//to target parent page from iframe

aBack.HRef = url;